# What is the make and model of this plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

I came across this picture taken in the late 1920s. Could you please help identify the make and model of this plane. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Some context would help, such as where was the picture taken, maybe who was the photographer, etc.

Comment: It was taken in 1929 in Burbank CA area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That info helped. Looks like a Travel Air 2000, but without the prop spinner.

[image: Travel Air 2000 at the Canada Aviation and Space Museum]

Comment: Thanks, Juan. It certainly looks a lot like it. I wonder what is in the bottom of the fuselage in the picture I posted. Some kind of radiator fin or just an open trap door?

Comment: https://youtu.be/AVQcRLPt5EIthis video confirms in. Thanks again, Juan.

Comment: Nice video, that looks like a sweet ride. At the bottom is a radiator indeed. The aircraft was powered by a Curtis OX-5 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_OX-5) or OX-6 engine (can't tell from the picture) and those were water-cooled engines. You're welcome, and don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]
It could have been a Swallow too. The propeller and wheels are similar.

[image]

Comment: The engine, exhaust and cowling are different, so are the wheel hubs.